# Issue with Flip view not displaying correctly on iOS with Appcelerator Titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, animation, titanium, appcelerator

I'm struggling with an issue on my flashcard iOS app built with Appcelerator (Titanium v 3.2.1).

Code snippet is below, the issue i'm experiencing is as follows....

User taps the masterview to animate between 2 child views, which each have a different language (in this case English/German).

The user can also swipe the view to load in a new word, by calling the loadWords() function again.

Everything is working perfectly, aside of 1 thing.

When the user has tapped the view once it shows the second language and they can happily tap and flip between the words with no issue.

Where we come unstuck is that if the user decides to swipe for a new word when they are on the second language (view: back), rather than the first (view: front) it loads in the new English word ok, but when they tap to view the German word it flips to show the english word again. If they tap again, it will then show the German word.

So I need to eliminate this extra display of the english word on the front view.

Any ideas?!

```
var win = Titanium.UI.currentWindow;

var selectedlanguage = Ti.App.Properties.getString('langSelect');

// detect height
if (Titanium.Platform.displayCaps.platformHeight == 480) {
    var MVTOP = 115;
    var tapTOP = 83;
    var swipeTOP = 275;
} else {
    var MVTOP = 165;
    var tapTOP = 133;
    var swipeTOP = 325;
}

var masterView = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: MVTOP,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 0.7
});

var state = true;

win.add(masterView);

var front = Ti.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 1.0,
    touchEnabled: false
});

var back = Titanium.UI.createView({
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: 300,
    height: 140,
    opacity: 1.0,
    touchEnabled: false
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_german,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});

var label2 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_english,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});

var word_id_num = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    //text: verb_english,
    text: '',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#000',
    font: {
        fontSize: 30
    },
    top: 50
});


var dropButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
    width: 120,
    height: 41,
    right: 15,
    bottom: 15,
    title: 'drop word',
    backgroundColor: '#fd0100',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    },
    opacity: 1.0
});

// add buttons to window
win.add(dropButton);


// the main function which controls the word display
function loadWords() {

    label1.text = '';
    label2.text = '';

    var state = true;


    // step 1. get a random pair of words (English & German)
    var db = Ti.Database.open('germanV6');
    var rows = db.execute('SELECT word_id, word_english, word_german FROM Words WHERE word_dropped = 0 ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 1;');

    var x = 0;
    while (rows.isValidRow()) {
        // step 2. set each label to the correct langauge (this comes from app.js when user selects their default language)
        if (selectedlanguage == 'en') {
            var word_1 = rows.fieldByName('word_english');
            var word_2 = rows.fieldByName('word_german');
        } else if (selectedlanguage == 'de') {
            var word_2 = rows.fieldByName('word_english');
            var word_1 = rows.fieldByName('word_german');
        }

        // step 3. set the word id, to be used later when wanting to 'drop' a word
        word_id_num.text = rows.fieldByName('word_id');

        rows.next();
    }

    // close database
    rows.close();

    //var state = true;

    label1.text = word_1;

    front.add(label1);
    masterView.add(front);

    label2.text = word_2;

    back.add(label2);

}

// fire the function and load our words into play
loadWords();


// labels for on screen prompts
var tapLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 200,
    top: tapTOP,
    text: 'tap to flip',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    }
});

var swipeLabel = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    width: 320,
    top: swipeTOP,
    text: 'swipe for next word',
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#FFF',
    font: {
        fontSize: 15
    }
});

// add to the window
win.add(tapLabel);
win.add(swipeLabel);


masterView.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    switch (state) {
    case true:
        Ti.API.info('true');
        masterView.animate({
            view: back,
            transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT
        });
        break;
    case false:
        Ti.API.info('false');
        masterView.animate({
            view: front,
            transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT
        });
        break;
    }
    state = !state;
});

// action for when label is swiped
swipeLabel.addEventListener('swipe', function (e) {
    alert(state);
    // reload the new word
    loadWords();
});

// action for when view is swiped
masterView.addEventListener('swipe', function (e) {
    // reload the new word
    loadWords();

});
```

If anyone can help, i'd be so grateful!

Simon

Comment: anyone able to help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try in this way also, you can specify your own animation for the view, you can use other property also:

```
var animation1 = Ti.UI.createAnimation();
animation1.view: back;
animation1.duration = 1000;
animation1.transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT;

var animation2 = Ti.UI.createAnimation();
animation2.view: front;
animation1.duration = 1000;
animatio2.transition: Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT;

masterView.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
switch (state) {
case true:
    Ti.API.info('true');
    masterView.animate(animation1, function(e){ 
        Ti.API.info('e-->'+e) });
    break;
case false:
    Ti.API.info('false');
    masterView.animate(animation2, function(e){
          Ti.API.info('e-->'+e)});
    break;
}
state = !state;
});
```

for more property for animation you can use below link:

http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Animation-property-view